# Real time trading app design - UX and React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-experience

I am working on a trading app which I need to design and code (in React).

People at trading desk have asked me to show data as tables inside the tiles. But they want to see all the data all the time and do not want to see the scroll in the table if data is more. If data is more in first tile, they dynamically want to see a new tile with rest of the data. Besides, this data will change real time and I might receive new trades every second.

I am still in design phase and do not have any UI to show but I have drawn something here to show what I am trying to ask.
[image: New tile]

Comment: First decide what you want to show, as all might not be possible as it has to accommodate Desktop, Tab, and Mobile I believe. Sector Wise | Portfolio Wise | Scrib. then  Script Name @ Exchange | Avg. Price | Current Price | Daily Percent Change |  Percent Change @ Avg. Price.

Comment: I think pushing data in a set number of tabs is possible, its just that you have to find out if it is already existing or you have to write it. say you allow 20 items in one listing in total 800 items for suppose, you have to create 40 tabs. so sorting will be important here.

Comment: Hi @vssadineni : we are targeting desktop and large screens at this stage. Also, they do not want to see tabs. Is there any other design I can recommend them?

Comment: It depends upon the priority, say Watch List: where users can search a script and add to watch list and for that you can provide number or named tabs. you could go to stock exchange web site and see the list of filters available. even more if you want to have a first hand experience go to investing.com site and create your own portfolio and see what is best needed for the user.

Comment: In my limited UX experience, whenever a table-based solution feels off, there is usually a way to break away from a standard table layout. This tweet is a nice example of breaking out of that layout, though it doesn't seem targetted for a large data set: https://twitter.com/steveschoger/status/997125312411570176

Comment: I do not mean that investing.com alone but similar once which are free to use, as it will be difficult to load all for first time users.Filters and pagination will help.